# How to format a double with leading zero and decimals in Java

Tags: java, double

**Requirements:**

- Leading zero (total 2 length) before the Dot
- 3 decimals

  // Example 1
  Input: double d = 1.2345
  Expected output:   01.234

  // Example 2
  Input: double d = 11.2345
  Expected output:   11.234

In C#, I can use:

```
double.ToString("00.###")
```

In Java:

```
String.format("%.3f", 1.2345) ->  1.234 -> No leading zero.
```

Comment: TL;DR of the duplicate `String.format("%06.3f", 1.2345)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00.###");
String formatted = df.format(1.2345); 
System.out.println( formatted );
```

Result:

```
01.234
```

Comment: IF you always want 3 decimals, for example 1.2 => 01.200, the pattern should be "00.000". IN general, in a pattern, "0" means always display a digit, while "#" means only display it if necessary.

Comment: True, if trailing zeroes after the decimal points need to be displayed it would be `00.000`.